# Any way to prevent game scaling to full screen in laptop?

Tags: laptop, resolution, gaming, windows-11

[Windows 11 | Laptop with Intel UHD 620 and NVIDIA 940MX | default resolution 1920x1080]

My NVIDIA GPU don't have those scaling options and settings probably because it is a laptop and I don't use an external display. So I must use Intel for changing scaling options.

Now, Intel probably recently did some changes in their graphics driver settings and now if your laptop resolution is set to 1920x1080, there's only one option available - *Maintain Display Scaling*. For all other resolutions there are other options available like Stretch, Maintain Aspect Ratio etc.

I'm mentioning above if this could be reason for my main problem (which I'm explaining below). But I personally don't think that's the reason.

You can't select "Maintain Aspect Ratio" or any other option like you could do 1 or 2 years ago.

Same is described under [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/intel-graphics-command-center-scaling-setting/9908724b-d946-4399-9e6f-a97193630faa) thread.

---

Now problem is, whenever I play any game in full screen with 1024x768 resolution, it stretches to full screen. What I want is black bars on left and right so game doesn't stretch.

The only solution I thought that might work is to first set desktop resolution to 1024x768 and then change scaling option to *Maintain Aspect Ratio*. **But that made no difference on game**. Only the laptop screen display becomes 4:3.

**In short, there's no effect of what I change in Intel resolution or scaling settings.** The game will scale it widescreen irrespective the game resolution is 4:3 (1024x768) or 16:9 (1280x720).

I tested it in more than one games and all have same problems.

The only games which don't have this problem is which have inbuilt 4:3 screen mode e.g., Cs 1.6

One way to "fix" this is by launching game in windowed mode instead of full screen but I don't like that.

Note: One moderator at Microsoft community also commented that it is probably because NVIDIA graphics don't have scaling options in laptop. So the game "doesn't care" what you set in Intel settings. I'm not sure he is right or not.

Because, interestingly, I've seen in some NVIDIA and other forums people asking how to change display scaling in laptop with NVIDIA 940MX so that they can play game without black bars. So they got response like you have to do this using Intel GPU only. And they were probably satisfied with response. My point is, I feel Intel GPU does make effect on games.

**So is there any other solution or workaround to solve this "issue"?**

I mainly need my games to behave like it has only 4:3 screen available so they won't stretch wide.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135269/discussion-on-question-by-vikas-any-way-to-prevent-game-scaling-to-full-screen-i).